# Can I have unique urls to the multi step signup form built using Django Wizard.

Tags: django, django-formwizard

I have used Django wizard form for a multi step signup.
But the URL for all the steps is the same. I would like to have unique URLs for each of the step. Is it possible to do it using wizard forms or should I use jquery and build a new multi step signup with unique URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`NamedUrlWizardView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#usage-of-namedurlwizardview) should provide the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: This is the one I am looking for!